# How to add value from TextBoxExt to sfdatagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

I'm trying to use syncfusion here, and it has a sfDataGrid and 2 sfTextBoxExt. 
 i create column headers in sfDataGrid :

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Variant", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Stok", typeof(string));
A_2_2_GridVariant.DataSource = dt;
```

then, I want to add data filled via sfTextBoxExt to sfDataGrid. How to do it ? 
any suggestions will be very useful for me.

Comment: if you have a data source, then you need to add the values to the data source (your DataTable). and then reassign it again to `A_2_2_GridVariant.DataSource` so that you can see the changes

Comment: @MongZhu thanks for your previous answer. it wasn't what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem now, and it might be useful to someone later.
First I create 2 columns :

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Variant", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Stok", typeof(string));
A_2_2_GridVariant.DataSource = dt;
```

to add the values ​​contained in the TextBoxExt to the sfDataGrid, I added 1 control button and added the code:

```
var addNewRow = A_2_2_GridVariant.View.AddNew() as System.Data.DataRow;
// Commits the newly created row.
A_2_2_GridVariant.View.CommitNew();
//
addNewRow.SetField(0, A_1_2_txtVariant.Text);
addNewRow.SetField(1, A_1_3_txtStok.Text);
```

yeaap.. this works fine for me.